# Multiple jQuery objects in Backbone view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am using JQuery and Backbone to build a website, and it seems like a recent update in Chrome has caused some weird behaviour. Here is my Backbone.js view class:

```
var WebView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#WebView',

    initialize: function() {
        ... // Do initialize actions

        // Arm the featured works link.
        this.$featuredWorks = $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',this.scrollTo);
    },

    scrollTo: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href')).ScrollTo();
    },
});
```

The thing is, the jQuery object works differently inside the View object as opposed to outside of it. I have imported a jQuery extension that adds `$.fn.ScrollTo` to jQuery, but it is only acccessible from **outside the View**, like so:

```
console.log($.fn.ScrollTo); // Returns the function.
var WebView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log($.fn.ScrollTo); // Returns null.
    },
});
```

Thus, to get ScrollTo working inside the View, I have to do the following:

```
var jq = jQuery;
var WebView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(jq.fn.ScrollTo); // This works. 
    },
});
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? Why does there seem to be 2 separate jQuery objects? This script is loaded via AJAX and run using `$.parseHTML`. Does this have anything to do with why this is happening?

Comment: Please share how you are loading the scripts, it is hard to solve the problem without being able to reproduce the problem or at least seeing how things are loaded

Comment: You can access jquery from everywhere. Can you show us your backbone and jquery import in index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. Turns out, I included jQuery twice in my HTML template document. The second one is deferred, so it loaded when all my other scripts were loaded. So the jQuery object on frame 1 is different from the jQuery objects after that.